# Give Google Cloud Vision API access to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Firebase on iOS, and I want to let users upload a photo to Firebase Storage. After that, I want to analyze the photo using Google Cloud Vision APIs.

Uploading works fine.

To analyze the photo, I'm specifying it using

```
image = {
    source = {
        gcsImageUri = "gs://app.name.from.firebase.console/path.to.photo";
    };
};
```

The problem is that I get the following error

```
error = {
    code = 7;
    message = "image-annotator::User lacks permission.: Calling GetObjectMetadata with file \"/bigstore/gs://app.name.from.firebase.console/path.to.photo\": cloud.bigstore.ResponseCode.ErrorCode::ACCESS_DENIED: ACCESS_DENIED: gaiaUser/0 does not have OBJECTS_GET access to object gs://app.name.from.firebase.console/path.to.photo.";
};
```

Do you have any suggestion w.r.t. what permissions I need to set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is because the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth) (GCS docs) that you created for using the Cloud Vision API and Firebase Storage (just a Google Cloud Storage bucket) together may not cover using both of them. How did you create your service account? According to [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth-template/cloud-api-auth#authenticating_with_application_default_credentials) (Cloud Vision docs)?

You can resolve this by creating a service account with permissions to read your bucket (ensure that the IAM role includes object GET). You may also have to add this service account to your default bucket and object ACLs if it isn't already (they usually do get added if they are created with the right IAM role for the bucket, but it's wise to check).

FWIW, [I have a project](http://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs) that does exactly this, so I'm surprised that a default service account wouldn't work for both of these things.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer. I'll check the service account docs and the instructions you posted. I checked your Flaming Specs, and I understand that it creates a new file from a Firebase photo and passes that file to Cloud Vision. I wanted a simpler solution, that just references the Firebase image.

Comment: I had created a service account while doing the Cloud Vision API tutorial. I gave that account read access to the Firebase bucket. Playing with the Google API Explorer, I noticed that if I run authenticated queries (with my own account), then it works. But, I have yet to figure out how to authenticate queries with the service account.

Comment: Hi, Mike. I have almost similar to this issue. Could you please give answer to this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101421/google-vision-api-is-not-working-after-upload-image-to-firebase

Answer (score 0):

I managed to temporarily fix the issue by giving Reader permission to allUsers on the bucket and also for the object default permissions.