# Google vision API is not working after upload image to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-vision

I built a image detection mobile app (e.g. Plastic Bottle, Aluminum Can, Milk Jug, etc.) with React-Native by using google vision API.

It worked well before and got response successfully.

But after I add Firebase image uploading function for store image, it (google vision api) didn't work.

In my guess, **Firebase image upload** and **google vision API** seems conflict and not compatible with each other.

Or in my image upload function, there seems error, but I am still not sure what is issue. Following is my code.

```
  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      setScannedURI(data.uri)
      imageUploadToFirebase(data)
      // callGoogleVisionApi(data.base64)  //============> After comment image upload function(above line) and if I call vision api here, it works well.
      setIsLoading(true)
    }
  };

  const imageUploadToFirebase = (imageData) => {
    const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;    //firebase image upload
    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
    window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
    window.Blob = Blob;
    const Fetch = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Fetch
    window.fetch = new Fetch({
      auto: true,
      binaryContentTypes: [
        'image/',
        'video/',
        'audio/',
        'foo/',
      ]
    }).build()
    let uploadBlob = null;
    var path = Platform.OS === "ios" ? imageData.uri.replace("file://", "") : imageData.uri
    var newItemKey = Firebase.database().ref().child('usersummary').push().key;
    var _name = newItemKey + 'img.jpg';
    setIsLoading(true)
    fs.readFile(path, "base64")
      .then(data => {
        let mime = "image/jpg";
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
      })
      .then(blob => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        Firebase.storage()
          .ref("scannedItems/" + _name)
          .put(blob)
          .then(() => {
            uploadBlob.close();
            return Firebase.storage()
              .ref("scannedItems/" + _name)
              .getDownloadURL();
          })
          .then(async uploadedFile => {
            setFirebaseImageURL(uploadedFile)
            // callGoogleVisionApi(imageData.base64)  //============> If I call here, it didn't work.
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log({ error });
          });
      });
  }
```

This is my callGoogleVisionApi function.

```
  const callGoogleVIsionApi = async (base64) => {
    let googleVisionRes = await fetch(config.googleCloud.api + config.googleCloud.apiKey, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "requests": [{
          "image": { "content": base64 },
          features: [
            { type: "LABEL_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 },
            { type: "WEB_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 }
          ],
        }]
      })
    })
      .catch(err => { console.log('Network error=>: ', err) })
    await googleVisionRes.json()
      .then(googleResp => {
        if (googleResp) {
          let responseArray = googleResp.responses[0].labelAnnotations
          responseArray.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.description != "" && item.description != undefined && item.description != null) {
              newArr.push(item.description)
            }
          })
        } 
      }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }
```

> Note: If I upload an image to firebase after getting the result from google vision api, the second call to vision api does not work.

I added my **callGoogleVIsionApi** function. (It is working well without Firebase image upload function.)

What will be the solution of this issue?

Comment: Looks like in your callGoogleVisionAPI function you pass a base64 string. You should submit the image URI in your API call instead of base64-encoded data.

Comment: I added my `callGoogleVIsionApi` function. But actually, if there is no Firebase image upload function, it is working well.

Comment: Can you read the image file and convert it to base 64 using this code : var fs = require('fs');
var imageFile = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file');
var encoded = Buffer.from(imageFile).toString('base64');   and then add the encoded base 64 data into "image": { "content": base64 } of callGoogleVisionApi as "Within the requests list:

image specifies the image file. It can be sent as a base64-encoded string, a Cloud Storage file location, or as a publicly-accessible URL" as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request)

Comment: @SatelBill Is your issue resolved? Have you tried the solutions provided to you? We expect some update on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, but I am still curious why.
Fetch blob and google vision seems conflict each other.
I changed Firebase image upload function, and it worked well.

Following is my modified Firebase image upload function.

```
const imageUploadToFirebase = () => {
      var path = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? scannedURI.replace('file://', '') : scannedURI;
      const response = await fetch(path)
      const blob = await response.blob();
      var newItemKey = Firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child('usersummary')
        .push().key;
      var _name = newItemKey + 'img.jpg';
      Firebase.storage()
        .ref(_name)
        .put(blob)
        .then(() => {
          return Firebase.storage()
            .ref(_name)
            .getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then(async uploadedFile => {
          let image = selectImage(sendItem.name?.toLowerCase());
          sendItem.image = image;
          sendItem.scannedURI = uploadedFile;
          AsyncStorage.getItem('@scanedItemList')
            .then(res => {
              if (res != null && res != undefined && res != '') {
                let result = `${res}#${JSON.stringify(sendItem)}`;
                AsyncStorage.setItem('@scanedItemList', result);
              } else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem(
                  '@scanedItemList',
                  JSON.stringify(sendItem),
                );
              }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log({error});
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using [`@google-cloud/vision`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/vision) package (in the `callGoogleVisionApi()` function) but as far as I know that is meant to be used in server side and authenticate with a service account. As an alternative to this method, you can use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) for Cloud functions which will trigger a function whenever a new file is uploaded and then use Cloud Vision API.

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. I added my `callGoogleVIsionApi` function. I didn't use any package. I just used google vision API.

Comment: @SatelBill can you share a screenshot of error if any? I'm not sure what you mean by it didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Vision API can use a base64-encoded image, a publicly accessible HTTP URI, or a blob in google cloud storage.

In order to use an HTTP URI you should change the JSON payload from your `callGoogleVisionAPI` function from this:

```json
{
        "requests": [{
          "image": { "content": base64 },
          features: [
            { type: "LABEL_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 },
            { type: "WEB_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 }
          ],
        }]
      }
```

to this:

```json
{
        "requests": [{
          "image": { "source": {"imageUri": 'https://PUBLIC_URI_FOR_THE_IMAGE' }  },
          features: [
            { type: "LABEL_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 },
            { type: "WEB_DETECTION", maxResults: 30 }
          ],
        }]
      }
```

You've got a better explanation here: [Make a Vision API request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#providing_the_image).

Comment: It can be a base 64 encoded string as well as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#providing_the_image)

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra - OP does not want to use that solution . The question states image data must be uploaded to firebase and vision api must take it from it (via http:// or gs:// url)